# Is there working example of OAuth2 with WebFlux

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-webflux

I'm trying to add OAuth2 to WebFlux and can't find any working example.

To Implement own Authorization Server I use such code:

```
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@Configuration
public class ServerAuth extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
...
}
```

And my  spring boot application stops working because inside **AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter** class there's usage of **AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer** which depends of **javax.servlet.Filter** but in the WebFlux application, there're no Servlet filters.

Also **AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer** expects to be initialized with **UserDetailsService** (old non reactive api) not reactive **UserDetailsRepository**

Is it possible to use oauth2 in the current WebFlux application if yes could you show the example.

Thanks

Comment: I'm also looking for such examples, did you find any ?

Comment: No,  it seems it is open issue.

Comment: As @MaxGrigoriev points it's still open, seems planned for spring 5.1.0 . See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/4807

Comment: Any workaround  ?

Comment: the issue is closed now, any examples now?

Answer (score 1):

Authorization server webflux support is yet to be implemented by the spring security team.

currently they have the resource server webflux support as the other answers mentioned. However, they mention here that they are working on Authorization server and based on this, it should be out soon:

> The OAuth 2.0 support is currently underway in Spring Security 5 with new Client support. The plan is to also provide support for Resource Server by mid-2018 and Authorization Server by the end of 2018 or early 2019. Our goal is to provide extensive support for OAuth 2.0 Core and Extensions, OpenID Connect 1.0, and Javascript Object Signing and Encryption (JOSE).

source: https://spring.io/blog/2018/01/30/next-generation-oauth-2-0-support-with-spring-security

so for now we are stuck with the servlet OAuth2 server which if you use JWT tokens should be good enough if you ask me.

Cheers!

Comment: Here's the ticket for tracking: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/6320

Answer (score -2):

It's implemented now, here the reference to the sample code:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/master/samples/boot/oauth2login-webflux

Comment: this is not a sample to create oauth2 server with webflux, it's only oauth2 client ..